# Excel VBA Could Not Extract The URL Body

Tags: excel, xml, vba, http, screen-scraping

I am trying to scrape and extract data from the link below by writing code in vba in excel:
http://www.tsetmc.com/Loader.aspx?ParTree=15131F

I used different techniques:

- MSXML2.XMLHTTP60               it does not work
- MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60         it does not work
- SHDocVw.InternetExplorer       beside it is too slow, it rarely works.

In Facts, when I open the link in Firefox or chrome, the page is ok and it is displayed correctly but when I request the page through "MSXML2.XMLHTTP60" or "MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60", the returned response is completely different from what it must be.

I am not sure but I guess the problem is related to one of the following cases:

- http://www.tsetmc.com/robots.txt    This site restrict the requesting.
- the site is based on asp.net and it could not be scraped.
- it is related to cookies. but in private mode of Firefox the url is displayed correctly.

In the request response, there is a "div" which is hidden and as I understood the phrase "Disallow: /WebResource.axd" in the robots.txt is related to the embedded contents and I guess the hidden div is used by server to find out if a browser is requesting or non-browser is scraping. I even set header in vba exactly similar to the browser header, but it did not work.

I should say that other links of this site have the similar behavior, for example:
http://www.tsetmc.com/Loader.aspx?ParTree=151311&i=20626178773287666
I read a lot of subjects but no solution worked.

Please help to find a solution and scrape the table in the mentioned URL.

```
Sub CreateMainList()
    
    Dim MainURL As String
    Dim XMLReq As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim HTMLDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim MainDiv As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim MainDivChildren As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim Res As String
    Dim price As Integer
    
    'MainURL = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Home").Range("C2").Value
    MainURL = "http://www.tsetmc.com/Loader.aspx?ParTree=15131F"

    XMLReq.Open "GET", MainURL, False
    'XMLReq.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    'XMLReq.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/html; charset=utf-8"
    'XMLReq.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/html; charset=utf-8"
    XMLReq.setRequestHeader "Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5"
    XMLReq.setRequestHeader "Connection", "keep-alive"
    XMLReq.setRequestHeader "accept-Encoding", "gzip , deflate"
    XMLReq.setRequestHeader "accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8"
    XMLReq.setRequestHeader "DNT", "1"
    'XMLReq.setRequestHeader "Upgrade-Insecure- Requests", "1"
    XMLReq.setRequestHeader "Set-Cookie", "ASP.NET_SessionId=cd03mksrog04g2ocuaeqxweb; path=/; HttpOnly"
    'XMLReq.setRequestHeader "Cache-Control", "Max-age = 0"


    'XMLReq.setRequestHeader "Cookie", MyCookie
    XMLReq.send
    
    If XMLReq.Status <> 200 Then
        MsgBox "Problem" & vbNewLine & XMLReq.Status & " - " & XMLReq.statusText
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Get the webpage response data into a variable.
    'response = StrConv(request.responseBody, vbUnicode)
    
    HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = XMLReq.responseText
    Debug.Print XMLReq.responseText
    
    Set XMLReq = Nothing
    
    Set MainDiv = HTMLDoc.getElementById("main")

    
End Sub
```

and the output is:

```
<!doctype html><html><head><title>.:TSETMC:. :: ÏíÏå ÈÇä ÈÇÒÇÑ íÔÑÝÊå</title><!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics --><script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-63076930-1"></script><script> window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}  gtag('js', new Date());  gtag('config', 'UA-63076930-1');</script><script>var DBFlag='1' ;var LongRunnigPagesSite='http://cdn2.tsetmc.com';function ens(ty,sv){var lv=localStorage.getItem("v_"+ty);var t;if (1==1 || lv!=sv){var oX=new XMLHttpRequest();oX.open('GET', 'tsev2/res/loader.aspx?t='+ty+'&_'+sv,false);oX.send(null);t=oX.responseText;if(t[t.length-1]!=';') return;localStorage.setItem("v_"+ty,sv);localStorage.setItem("t_"+ty,t)}else{t=localStorage.getItem("t_"+ty)}if (ty=='s'){document.write("<style>"+t+"</style>")}else{var h=document.getElementsByTagName('HEAD').item(0);var s=document.createElement("script");s.defer=true;s.text=t;h.appendChild(s)}}var version='472';ens('j',version); ens('s',v
ersion);  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)  })</script></head><body><div style="display:none">PSB is being developed by Pooya Paridel.</div><div id="FastView" class="slideTop"></div><div id="TopBar"><div id="company"><div id="company_logo"></div><div id="company_text">ÔÑßÊ ãÏíÑíÊ ÝäÇæÑí ÈæÑÓ ÊåÑÇä<br/> Tehran Securities Exchange Technology Management Co</div></div><div id="menu_btns"></div><script>ShowMenuIcon(1)</script></div><div class="MainContainer"><form method="post" action="./Loader.aspx?ParTree=15131F" id="form1">
<div class="aspNetHidden">
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="" />
</div>

<div id="display" style="direction:rtl;font-size:12px;text-align:right">
</div>
<script>
    ens('g', version);
    if (location.href.split('&')[1] == "E")
    {ens('me', version); mw = MarketWatchPlus(); mw.StartMarketWatch() }
    else {
        ens('p', version); ens('tw', version); tw = TweetEngine();mw = MarketWatchPlus(); mw.StartMarketWatch()
    }
</script>
</form>
</div></body></html>
```

Comment: "does not work" is not a useful description of what happens when you tried what you tried.

Comment: The page is dynamically built after the first resource loads, so you will need to use either IE or Chrome (with Selenium for example) to fetch this information.  You can't use XMLHTTP

Comment: should the page load completely when using Selenium? if yes, it would be so slow.
isn't there any better way? for example PHP (and its framework) does not help with this challenge?

Comment: If you want the full page content then you have to load all of the components.  It doesn't matter what you use on the client-side if the server is the limiting factor in serving up the content.  Likely they didn't build it to make it easy for you to scrape.

Comment: Nice and simple description. Could you please reopen the topic? So there is no way to scrape this site fast? Could you please describe what you mean by the word dynamically in "The page is dynamically built after the first resource loads"?

Comment: And why "www.googletagmanager.com" exists in the response?

Comment: Lots of people use Google analytics to track their site visitors/usage.  And dynamically means the final content is not delivered in response to your request - typically there's some javascript which executes in your browser to build the page once loaded, often by making other requests to the server for more content.